# How to send all email coming into Debian to a PHP script?

Tags: sendmail, exim

How can I send ALL email coming into Debian to a PHP script? I have exim4 installed, but when i send en email to username@ipaddress nothing happens! I've tried a few exim4 configuration tutorials around the internet but none of them seem to work!

Is there some other mail server I should try? Sending mail via php used to work fine, but that's also broken now...

Who thought the idea of having 100 different config files was a good idea!?

This is Debian 6, and I have installed the exim4-base package.

Comment: I don't know about exim (I use postfix), but I know you can use spampd http://www.worlddesign.com/Content/rd/mta/spampd/spampd.html as an SMTP proxy.  Incomming connections go to spampd, then your SMTP posting host listens to the output of spampd.  Spamassassin can then intercept messages.  There are lots of recepies for installing your own scripts into Spamassassin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create transport that points to the your script:

```
myscript:
        driver          = pipe
        user            = www
        command         = /path/to/the/script.php -a -b -c
```

Then you have to set up the router:

```
gotcha:
        driver          = accept
        domains         = +local_domains
        transport       = myscript
        no_more
```

When message arrives router accept it and pass to the transport. Transport launch the script exactly as shown as user `www` and pass the message to the `stdin` of the script. So you have to read `stdin` till the EOF and then you can do whatever you want.